# Couchbase Server unable to start

Tags: couchbase

I am unable to start my couchbase server.  I am getting this error while I run the server.

```
          supervisor: {local,inet_gethost_native_sup}
             started: [{pid,<0.266.0>},{mfa,{inet_gethost_native,init,[[]]}}]

[error_logger:info,2015-01-06T18:14:37.164,nonode@nohost:error_logger<0.6.0>:ale_error_logger_handler:do_log:203]
=========================PROGRESS REPORT=========================
          supervisor: {local,kernel_safe_sup}
             started: [{pid,<0.265.0>},
                       {name,inet_gethost_native_sup},
                       {mfargs,{inet_gethost_native,start_link,[]}},
                       {restart_type,temporary},
                       {shutdown,1000},
                       {child_type,worker}]

[ns_server:warn,2015-01-06T18:14:37.189,nonode@nohost:dist_manager<0.264.0>:dist_manager:wait_for_address:118]Cannot listen on address `10.219.59.100`: eaddrnotavail
[ns_server:info,2015-01-06T18:14:37.189,nonode@nohost:dist_manager<0.264.0>:dist_manager:wait_for_address:122]Configured address `10.219.59.100` seems to be invalid. Giving OS a chance to bring it up.
[ns_server:warn,2015-01-06T18:14:38.190,nonode@nohost:dist_manager<0.264.0>:dist_manager:wait_for_address:118]Cannot listen on address `10.219.59.100`: eaddrnotavail
[ns_server:info,2015-01-06T18:14:38.190,nonode@nohost:dist_manager<0.264.0>:dist_manager:wait_for_address:122]Configured address `10.219.59.100` seems to be invalid. Giving OS a chance to bring it up.
```

Is it Ip address Problem ? My Ip address Is 10.219.59.102 but it looking for 10.219.59.100.

Comment: Can you start on your machine any other TCP/IP socket server (like apache http server)? also have you tried to clean/reinstall it?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the IP address the node was originally configured for has changed. If you don't specify a hostname as the node's name when you first configured the node, Couchbase will attempt to auto-detect the node's public IP address and use that. However if that IP address changes then it runs into problems.

Take a look at the Install guide, specifically the section on [Using hostnames](http://docs.couchbase.com/admin/admin/Install/hostnames.html) for how to change a node's name.